# Read text file line by line and Count specific word with particular values from a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below data is saved in a text file. I can read that file line by line.
Now, I want to start counting the "FBC = " and want to stop counting when it contains some specific value and save the line above "FBC".

Block = 150

Erase time= 1830, Cycle= 0

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFF,FFBBFFFF,FFFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 265,

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FFFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 355,

Read time= 1623, Cycle= 1,CCFFBFFF,CCBBFFFF,CCFFFF8F,CCFBFFCC,

Page = 9600 FBC = 505,

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 642,

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFC,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 718,

Block = 150

Erase time= 1830, Cycle= 0

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFF,FFBBFFFF,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 235,

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFF,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 310,

Read time= 1623, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 445,

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DDFFFFFC,DDBBFFFB,DDEFFF8F,DDFBFFDD,

Page = 9600 FBC = 565,

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFF7FFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFFBF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 680,

```
Please help me to count `FBC` with particular values.
Please note, there will be more sections like these.

I tried the below-mentioned code, which can only count the Total FBC (Like 10). My expected result is also included below.

    filename="Test.txt";
    data_page=READ_DATA(filename);
    def READ_DATA(filename):
        infile = open(filename,'r') # open file for reading
        lines = (line.rstrip() for line in infile)
        lines = (line for line in lines if line)

        FBC=[];
        count =0;Flag=0;
        for line in lines:
            #if line.find("FBC = ") != -1:
            if line.find("FBC = ") >= 500:
                count=count+1;
        print count

Expected output: it should stop counting when `FBC > 500`. So, for 1st Section, output will be `count = 3` and save `[CCFFBFFF,CCBBFFFF,CCFFFF8F,CCFBFFCC,]`.

For 2nd section, output will be `count = 4` and save `[DDFFFFFC,DDBBFFFB,DDEFFF8F,DDFBFFDD,]`.
```

Comment: Are all sections in the same file ?

Comment: read csv, convert them into list of dictionary, enable search. You'll be golden.

Comment: @mujjiga, actually there is no section. They are all together in one text file. I divided them into two separate parts to make it feasible to understand the Qs easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    count, found = 0, False
    pat = re.compile(r'\bFBC\s*=\s*(\d+),\s*(.+)')
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if line.startswith('section_'):
                count, found = 0, False
            elif 'FBC' in line and not found:
                count += 1
                num, part = pat.search(line).groups()
                if int(num) >= 500:
                    found = True
                    print('count', count)
                    print('line to save', part)   # do save/write logic
```

If there's no `section_` lines - use the following condition instead `if line.startswith('Block'):`

---

Sample output (for your current input text):

```
count 3
line to save DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,
count 4
line to save DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFFBF,
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. Thanks to my friend & @RomanPerekhrest:

```
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if line.startswith('Block'):
                Rcount, found = 0, False
            elif 'Read time' in line and not found:
                readLine = line
                Rcount += 1
                nextLine = next(f)
                if 'FBC' in nextLine and not found:
                    num = pat.search(nextLine).groups()
                    num = ''.join(map(str, num)) 
                    if int(num) >= 500:
                        found = True
                        print Rcount
                        print readLine
                        TotalCount.append(count)
```

O/P:

3

Read time= 1623, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFCC,

4

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFDDD,